# Page not found when passing parameters via URL in Django

Tags: python, regex, django

I suspect it may be something to do with the way I am styling my regular expressions, because I get the following output when I try to go to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/recipes/search/fish/ for example...

Using the URLconf defined in gfp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^recipes/$
^recipes/category/(?P<category>\d+)/$
^recipes/search/(?P<term>\d+)/$
^recipes/view/(?P<slug>\d+)/$
^admin/
```

The current URL, recipes/search/fish/, didn't match any of these.

For reference here is my URLconf

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^recipes/', 'main.views.recipes_all'),
url(r'^recipes/category/(?P<category>\d+)/$', 'main.views.recipes_category'),
url(r'^recipes/search/(?P<term>\d+)/$', 'main.views.recipes_search'),  
url(r'^recipes/view/(?P<slug>\d+)/$', 'main.views.recipes_view'),
```

For reference here are the views I am attemping to use at the moment

```
def recipes_all(request):
    return HttpResponse("this is all the recipes")

def recipes_category(request, category):
    return HttpResponse("this is the recipes category % s" % (category))

def recipes_search(request, term):
    return HttpResponse("you are searching % s in the recipes" % (term))

def recipes_view(request, slug):
    return HttpResponse("you are viewing the recipe % s" % (slug))
```

I suspect it is my regular expression, would anyone be able to explain what is wrong with it please? I have seen /w(?) used on some url regex, but it doesnt go into it in the Django tuorial here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'^recipes/search/(?P<term>\d+)/$'` matches `/recipes/search/123456/`
while `'^recipes/search/(?P<term>[-\w]+)/$'` is probably what you need. (Updated with hyphens)

Take a look at [Python re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) docs to understand what '\d', '\w' and others mean.

Comment: thanks aswell! that works, is a \d numeric and a \w char? How could I allow for hyphens line-this, as it looks like \w will not accept this? I guess \d doesnt either?

Comment: `\w` usually any alphanumeric character and the underscore

Comment: so I should just store my slug as the name with underscores? as the slugify field in django uses - - - dashes

Comment: It's ok when slug contains hyphens. Just use regexp that I provided `[-\w]+`

Answer (score 1):

You urlpattern for `recipe/search` only allows numbers (`\d`) for the search term. Change it to `\w`, and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks! so is \d numeric and \w char, or varchar?